# Validate that the first two strings have at least 3 characters each

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a single input where I need the user to type the first and last name. But I need a validation, I need to check that the first two words have at least three characters.

For example, if I type "Joe Do" or "Jo Doe" or even "Jo Do" I return a boolean value with the value false.

I tried using the following regex:

```
isValidName= /^(\w{3,20})(\s)(\w{3,20})$/g.test(name)
```

However, if I type a third string the validation stops working.

I have little knowledge with regex, so thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your regex is that you're anchoring the end of the second word with a `$`, which forces a matching string to have exactly two words. You can use `\b` to assert a word boundary instead at the end of the second word:

```
^\w{3,20}\s\w{3,20}\b
```